# If I have webpack installed globally on my computer and also as a dev dependency, which one runs?

Tags: webpack, node-modules

To reiterate, let's say I have the latest version of webpack installed globally on my computer and I clone a repository from Github which has a specified version of webpack as a dev dependency.

After I run npm install, and then run webpack, which version of webpack will be run? The one installed globally on my computer or the one I downloaded into my node_modules folder?

Comment: I just tested this out and based on my findings, it uses the local dev dependency. However, I'm not sure if that's always the case though, there may be some exceptions.

Comment: So I'm guessing there is no need to specify, it automatically chooses the version that's in node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify OS, but "where webpack" (on Windows) or "whereis webpack" (on linux) will show the location hierarchy of the script runtime.